# Questions about proof for Erdős-Gallai theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading *Graphs, Algorithms, and Optimization* by Kocay and Kreher and I am confused about a proof they give for the Erdős-Gallai Theorem

Theorem 1.6. (Erdős-Gallai theorem)
Let $D = (d_{1}, d_{2}, \dots , d_{n})$, where $d_1 \geq d_{2} \geq \dots \geq d_{n}$. Then $D$ is graphic if and only if

1. $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}d_{i}$ is even
2. $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}d_{i} \leq k(k − 1) + \sum_{i = k+1}^{n} \min(d_i,k)$, for $k=1, 2, \dots , n$.

The proof is by induction on $S = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}d_{i}$. If $S = 2$, it is clear that the result is true. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $d_n \geq 1$. Let $t$ be the smallest integer such that $d_t > d_{t+1}$, if there is one. Otherwise, if all $d_i$ are equal, we take $t = n − 1$.

Construct $D′ =(d_{1}',...,d_{n}')$ from $D$ as follows: if $i \neq t$ and $i \neq n$, then $d_{i}' =d_{i}$; if $i=t$ or $i=n$ ,then $d_{i}' = d_{i} −1$. That is, we are looking for a graph with degree sequence $D$ in which vertex $t$ is adjacent to vertex $n$. Then $S′ = S − 2$. If we can verify that $D′$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem, with corresponding graph $G′$, we can then construct a graph $G$ with degree sequence $D$.

Consider $S_k = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} d_{i}$ and $S_{k}' = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} d_{i}'$. Let $T_k = k(k − 1) + \sum_{i = k+1}^{n} \min(d_i,k)$, and similarly for $T_{k}'$.

Case (1): If $k \geq t$, then $S_{k}′ = S_{k} − 1 \leq T_{k}−1 \leq T_{k}′$. Thus the conditions of the theorem are satisfied when $k \geq t$.

If $k < t$ there are several cases to consider. Note that when $k < t$, $d_1 = d_2 = \dots = d_k$, so that $S_k′ = S_k = kd_{k}$.

Case (2): If $k<t$ and $d_k < k$ , then $S_{k}′ =kd_{k} \leq k(k−1) \leq T_{k}′$.

Case (3): If $k < t$ and $d_k = k$, then $S_{k}′ = kdk = k^2 = k(k−1) + k$ . Now $d_{k+1}'$ is either $k$ or $k − 1$. Therefore, when $i > k$, $\min(d_{i}',k) = d_{i}'$. If $d_{k+1}' = k$, then $S_{k}′ = k(k−1) + d_{k+1}' ≤Tk′$. Otherwise $d_{k+1}' = k − 1$,and $S_{k}′ = k(k−1) + d_{k+1}′ + 1$. If $d_{k+2}' \geq 1$, we obtain $S_{k}′ \leq T_k$. Otherwise $n = k + 2$ and $t = n − 1$, so that $d_n = 1$, giving $S =(n−2)^{2} + (n − 2) + 1$, which must be even, so that $n$ is odd. But then all degrees are odd, which is impossible.

The authors consider more cases, but I am currently stuck on case (3)

Why is $d_{k+1}'$ either $k$ or $k − 1$?

Also, why is the following true: Otherwise (when $d_{k+2}' < 1$, I assume), $n = k + 2$ and $t = n − 1$?

**Edit**:

Case (4): If $k<t$ and $d_{k} > k$ and $d_{n} > k$, the $\min(d_{i}, k) = \min(d_{i}', k) = k$ when $i>k$. This implies $S_{k}' = kd_{k} = S_{k} \leq T_{k} = T_{k}'$.

Case (5): If $k < t$ and $d_{k}>k$ and $d_{n} \leq k$, let $r$ be the first integer such that $d_{r} \leq k$. Then $r > t$ and $\min(d_{i},k) = d_{i}$ when $i \geq r$

in Case (5), why is $r > t$?

Comment: From a quick read : $k<t$ means that $d_k=d_{k+1}$ (by minimality of $t$). Therefore $d_{k+1}=k$. Now for any $i$, $d'_i$ is either $d_i$ or $d_i-1$, so $d'_{k+1}=k$ or $k-1$.

Comment: For the second question, if it is <1, then it must be 0, as it is an integer. Because all initial degree are at least 1, then it means that $d_{k+2}=1$. Because there were no initial vertices with degree 0, then for any $i>k+2$, we had $d_i=1$, and we cannot have $t=k+2$, therefore we were in the second case, $k+2=n$ and $t=n-1$

Comment: @Thomas Lesgourgues Thanks for the replies, they were very helpful. I edited the question to include two more cases and I added a question about Case (5). I would appreciate it if you could also answer that question. Thanks!

Comment: Case $(5)$, $t>k$ implies that $d_1=\ldots=d_k=\ldots=d_t$ and then $d_r\leq k < d_k$ implies r >t.